# MIPS lw from .asciiz in data

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to load an .asciiz parameter into a register, and I get an error,
code:

```
.data


    stp:
    .asciiz "stop"

.text

.globl main

main:

la $t1, stp
lw $t1, 0($t1)
```

I get an exception: Unaligned address in inst/data fetch,

is there a way to load an .ascii to a register as a word?

I want to compare an input variable to the text saved in stp,
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want `lb` or `lbu` instruction for sign- or zero-extended byte sized loads, respectively.

If you want to load all 4 characters as a word, then make sure the string is aligned by adding the appropriate assembler directive (such as `.align 2`) Alternatively, use the `ulw` pseudo instruction that you assembler will turn into the proper sequence.

Comment: It's a pseudo-instruction, the assembler will replace it with generated code. GNU assembler for example turns it into `LWL` and `LWR`. You can of course write equivalent code yourself.

Comment: Thanks, though I didn't get the results I wanted with the `ulw`, but the `.align n` did help.